# How do I deal with "unpacking of archive failed ... cpio: symlink"?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, rpm, centos-7

I've gotten stuck on a problem. I'm packaging an existing project into an RPM. It builds fine but when I run

`sudo yum localinstal --nogpgcheck <path to rpm>`

I get the following error message:

`Error: unpacking of archive failed on file <path to symlink>;5656d545: cpio: symlink`

The RPM extracts the project into a directory and then updates an existing symlink `latest` to point to it by doing `ln -sfn <app name and version>/ latest`

Google yields next to nothing on this issue so I'm hoping that someone with more experience in these matters could offer a hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happen when rpm package owns some directory or file while on the disk the file/directory is symlink. Or vice versa.
This is known issue for long time.

You either have to manually remove the symlink before installing/upgrading the package. Or alter the package to not own that file.

Comment: Related: I was getting `error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: lstat` because I had a stray file on the filesystem where the RPM expected a directory to be.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with CentOS 7.6 and Crystal.

```
Downloading packages:
crystal-0.27.2-1.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                              |  38 MB  00:00:02
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : crystal-0.27.2-1.x86_64                                                                                                                      1/1
Error unpacking rpm package crystal-0.27.2-1.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/share/crystal/src/lib_c/amd64-unknown-openbsd: cpio: rename
  Verifying  : crystal-0.27.2-1.x86_64                                                                                                                      1/1

Failed:
  crystal.x86_64 0:0.27.2-1

Complete!
```

I ended up deleting the entire path in question: `/usr/share/crystal/*`
which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when I had a symlink pointing to a directory that didn't exist; for example i had a symlink from `/opt/` going to `/data/`, but `/data/` didn't exist because i had a spelling error when i mounted the drive (`/daat/` if you're wondering).

Make sure your symlink is pointing to a valid location if it's supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (but different) problem, and since this Q&A is the first hit I got while searching, I thought I would record my experience here.

In my case, the error message from rpm was:

`Error: unpacking of archive failed on file /dir1/file;xxxxxxxx: cpio: link failed: Directory not empty`

In my case, `/dir1/file` is a hard link to another file inside the RPM package; call it `/dir2/file`.

Using strace, I learned the sequence of events leading up to the failure:

- rpm creates the directories in the package
- rpm extracts `/dir2/file` successfully
- rpm calls `linkat` to create the hard link `/dir1/file`, which fails with `EXDEV` (cross-device link not permitted)
- rpm removes the stuff it has installed, including the directories
- one of those directories already exists with contents, so the `rmdir` fails with `ENOTEMPTY`
- rpm fails with the error message above

I was trying to install the package on a system where `/dir1` and `/dir2` are on different partitions, causing the `EXDEV` failure when creating the hard link. Instead of recording that failure, however, rpm reports the errno from the later `rmdir` performed during cleanup. This appears to be a bug in rpm; in my case, version 4.16.1.3.